# PostgreSQL: calculate cumulative time spent in each state

Tags: postgresql

Given a table of timestamped state changes, how can I calculate the total time spent in each state?

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE states (state text, dt timestamp without time zone);
INSERT INTO states (state, dt) VALUES ('blue',  '2023-02-21T00:00:00');
INSERT INTO states (state, dt) VALUES ('green', '2023-02-21T01:00:00');
-- redundant info - "still in this state" - should be handled correctly
INSERT INTO states (state, dt) VALUES ('green', '2023-02-21T02:00:00');
INSERT INTO states (state, dt) VALUES ('orange', '2023-02-21T03:00:00');
-- state with no end (no next state) should be handled correctly
INSERT INTO states (state, dt) VALUES ('red', '2023-02-21T05:00:00');
```

I want a query that produces "1 hour spent in state blue, 2 hours in green", etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a window query

```sql
select 
    state, 
    sum(
      -- if there is no lead (next row), assume that state continues
      -- until the present
      COALESCE(lead_dt, NOW()) - dt
    ) duration
from  ( 
    select
        t.*,
        lead(dt) over(order by dt) lead_dt
    from states t
) t
group by state
order by state;
```

This produces (at the moment I'm writing this):

```
 state  |    duration
--------+-----------------
 blue   | 01:00:00
 green  | 02:00:00
 orange | 02:00:00
 red    | 04:58:43.250921
```

Of course, the later the date and time are when you run this, the larger the time spent in the last state will be, since its end is `NOW()`.

(Credit: based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62136185/4376), which was for SQL Server.)

The code above does *not* take into account situations where you want to report on a period from (say) `00:30` to `4:30`.

To handle starting at `00:30`, you'd need to find all the state changes that fall in your period, and also find the last state change that falls before your period (have a separate query find the 1 record preceding the given period (`ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 1`) and `UNION` those, then calculate the first period as beginning at `00:30` rather than `00:00` as the first record indicates.

To handle ending at `04:30` you'd need to parameterize that value and use that it the end time for the last period when `lead_dt` is absent - `COALESCE(lead_dt, $1)`.